# Rails 6 doesn’t pick up configuration change or new gem automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 6 and puma-dev. I notice whenever I add a gem, or change a config file, Rails doesn’t pick up the changes or new gem. I have tried ‘touch tmp/restart.txt’ but to no avail.

Initially I thought something was wrong, until I return to my computer next morning and the app took time to reload, and everything gets well again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using `puma-dev`. All I needed to do was to kill puma and reload my app. Run `puma-dev --stop` to kill.